# MATE remove window list from panel using dconf write or

Tags: panel

I see that I just have to find 'the right spot' to right click, but I fail and fail. Every where I click the click goes to the nearest window in the list.

I've tried editing the dconf dump file to remove the windowlist but I discover that is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use `gsettings` instead of `dconf`.
Simple hacky way:

```
gsettings set org.mate.panel object-id-list \
"$(gsettings get org.mate.panel object-id-list | sed "s/'window-list', //")"
```

Explanation. On my clean installation of Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS the output of

```
gsettings get org.mate.panel object-id-list
```

is

```
['briskmenu', 'firefox', 'notification-area', 'indicatorappletcomplete', 'clock', 'show-desktop', 'window-list', 'workspace-switcher', 'trashapplet']
```

With `| sed "s/'window-list', //"` piping we can remove `'window-list',` from parameter value and change it to the following:

```
['briskmenu', 'firefox', 'notification-area', 'indicatorappletcomplete', 'clock', 'show-desktop', 'workspace-switcher', 'trashapplet']
```

then we pass this value to `gsettings set org.mate.panel object-id-list`.

---

Note: this method is also suitable for Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Thanks N0rbert but the problem is that I have two window lists and want to remove only one of them. If I am following the logic of your suggestion it would remove all instances. I suppose it would be easy enough to add one after removing them all. I could even rebuild the entire panel without much effort, but it would be nice to have fine CLI control of the panel for panel applets that don't offer a clear easily accessible click context for applet-level control.

Comment: Thanks, this explained how to get rid of an applet that I had added to the panel that did not actually appear on the panel!